# Top aligned UILabel, make text stick to top of label view -ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a way to "top align" a UILabel, that is make text stick to top of label view? As opposed to center aligned vertically, or float in the center of the view, as is the default?

Here is an image of three labels, aligned left, right and center, and a UITextView that is aligned center and top. The text of the textView sticks to the top regardless of the vertical size of the view. Can I do the same thing with a label?

[image]

Comment: Here's an answer I gave to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel/1054681#1054681

Comment: This link did it for me. Thanks nevan king! Anyone having the same issue as me can go to the link above, or check out my answer below, and I think you will find the solution.

Comment: QUICK TRICK ... simply sizeToFit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to set the vertical alignment of a `UILabel` by default in iOS. Instead, you will want to use one of the `sizeWithFont` methods provided by `NSString`. Which one you use depends on whether you want a multi-line or single-line label. `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` can be used for single-line labels, while `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` can be used for multi-line labels. You can easily load the font parameter with the `font` property of the label in question. You can look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for some more details on using these functions.

These methods will return a `CGSize` struct with the minimum size for your label based on the text in the `NSString`. Once you have the correct size for the label, you can easily place it at the top of your superview and it will appear to be top-aligned.

Comment: You can also call sizeToFit on the label to set the frame to its contents.

Answer (score 39):

There's a workaround for it:

1. Set a height & width `constraint` to your `UILabel` with a constant <= to the maximum height|width you want.
2. Set `number of lines` to zero.
3. Set the height in `storyboard` to fit only one line.
4. In your code after setting the text of `UILabel` call `sizeToFit`.

This would make your `UILabel` to resize within the bounds of the maximum width & height you want and text will always be top aligned.

Comment: Also setting the constraint for the height to >= whatever the original height was will allow the label to grow and stay upper left with the text  in the container.

Comment: Ran into this with a `UICollectionViewCell`. The regular sizeToFit wasn't working. Your autolayout suggestion worked in this instance. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your post, it works like a charm on iOS 11 for those who wonder :)

Comment: make sure you use <= not just set = to a value less than the maximum height. I was not getting this but now it works

Comment: what do u mean by step 1 and step 3?

Comment: doing this after setting one parameter in android studio for same effect feels bad

Comment: what if we don't want to change uilabel height ?

Answer (score 12):

I used the answer linked above from [nevan king](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74118/nevan-king) in a comment to my question: [Vertically align text to top within a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel/1054681#1054681)

The code I used is here:

```
- (void)setUILabelTextWithVerticalAlignTop:(NSString *)theText {
    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(250, 300);
    CGSize theStringSize = [theText sizeWithFont:targetLabel.font constrainedToSize:labelSize lineBreakMode:targetLabel.lineBreakMode];
    targetLabel.frame = CGRectMake(targetLabel.frame.origin.x, targetLabel.frame.origin.y, theStringSize.width, theStringSize.height);
    targetLabel.text = theText;
}

//linked to a button that sets the text from a UITextView to the label.
- (IBAction)setText:(id)sender {

    [sourceText resignFirstResponder];
    [self setUILabelTextWithVerticalAlignTop:sourceText.text];
    [targetLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [targetLabel sizeToFit];

}
```

Here is the project:

[owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/verticalAlignUILabel.zip](http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/verticalAlignUILabel.zip)

Comment: Working for me with iOS 11 code updated: `UILabel *iconLabel = [UILabel.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size)];
    [iconLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [iconLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    CGSize labelSize = iconLabel.frame.size;
    iconLabel.frame = [icon boundingRectWithSize:labelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:nil context:nil];

    [iconLabel setText:icon];
    [iconLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    [iconLabel sizeToFit];
    return iconLabel;`

Answer (score 7):

I have replaced UILabel with UITextView, because in UITextView, the text sticks to the top.

Just a suggestion, it may be useful for someone.

Comment: Useful to me :) How do make it multi-line though? I cant seem to find an option which allows this :/

Comment: Yes it works but plz tell me how should i change its font size. I have my TextView on a custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

Make a subclass of UILabel

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIControlContentVerticalAlignment verticalAlignment;
```

.m file

```
- (void) drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    if(_verticalAlignment == UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop ||  _verticalAlignment == UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom)    
    {
         // If one line, we can just use the lineHeight, faster than querying sizeThatFits
         const CGFloat height = floorf(((self.numberOfLines == 1) ? ceilf(self.font.lineHeight) : [self sizeThatFits:self.frame.size].height));
          rect.origin.y = floorf(((self.frame.size.height - height) / 2.0f) * ((_verticalAlignment == UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop) ? -1.0f : 1.0f));
    }
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}


- (void) setVerticalAlignment:(UIControlContentVerticalAlignment)newVerticalAlignment
{
     _verticalAlignment = newVerticalAlignment;
     [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I used this for Vertical Alignment .

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy solution for cases where the height of a label doesn't need to be constant: put your `Label` in a `Stack View`. Be sure to add leading and trailing constants to the `Stack View`.
Here is a screenshot of how to do it in storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my app was to set the UILabel's line property to 0 as well as to create a bottom constraint of the `UILabel` and make sure it is being set to >= 0 as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in `collectionviewCell`, I wanted my label to contain text I set to be top align, so I found a way to get it done is I took a uiview first which I set to height and width of `contentview` of `collectionview` then I added my `imageview` and label to the `UIView`. I set height and width of imageview and for label I just gave trailing, leading and top.

[image: My collectionview]